Finding the group of all models for predefined sets
Given a set of theorems $T$, define $M(T)$ to be a set containing all models of $T$.
A set of assignments $K$ is called "Hedgeable" if exists a set of theorems $T$ s.t. $M(T)=K$, otherwise K is non-hedgeable.
How (and what does it mean) can i find $M(T)$ for the following sets:
$$
T_1=\{All\ \ atomic\ \   variables\}\\T_2=\emptyset \\T_3=\{\ all \ tautologies\}\\T_4=\{ all \ contradictions\}
$$
I'm simply unsure on how to approach this, for example it seems like $M(T_2)$ would be $\emptyset$ simply because there's no elements in $T_2$ that can be assigned a truth/false value.
